# How to do a outer join in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

**This is my sql query**

```
SELECT * FROM candidate A
LEFT JOIN form B ON A.canid = B.canid
UNION
SELECT * FROM candidate A
RIGHT JOIN form B ON A.canid = B.canid
```

Comment: left outer join or right outer join. Also, from your question it isn't what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Joins in jpa are same as in sql jdbcTemplate. Joins in your above query are fine

SELECT * FROM candidate A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.canid = B.canid
UNION
SELECT * FROM candidate A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN B ON A.canid = B.canid